# Homebrew: list available versions with new formula@version format

Tags: homebrew

Homebrew recently deprecated `homebrew/versions` in favour of making versions available on `homebrew/core` via the new `formula@version` format. For example (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/1469018)), you can do `brew install postgresql@9.5`.

Of course, this doesn't work for arbitrary versions. For instance, `install cocoapods@1.1.1` turns up "Error: No formulae found in taps".

Under the old method, I could run `brew versions <formula>` to see available versions. How do I list available versions now?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can search versions using `brew search`.

For example:

```
$ brew search postgresql
postgresql ✔      postgresql@9.4     postgresql@9.5
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... The program I need an old version for only has the current version available. Ah well.

Comment: This method is pretty useless for a package like `r`; it finds every package with an "r" in its name.

Comment: How do I prevent `brew search` from including things like `github` when I search for `git`?

Comment: @KenWilliams @aaron See this answer for how to do an exact search for `r` or `git`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538993/homebrew-list-available-versions-with-new-formulaversion-format/70491376#70491376

Comment: Thanks @wisbucky, I didn't realize it could use a regex.

Answer (score 73):

This is an old question, but I found a "better" (for me) way to do this:

```
brew info --json PACKAGE_NAME | jq -r '.[].versioned_formulae[]'
```

For example, in the case of the package `node`, this will print:

```
$ brew info --json node | jq -r '.[].versioned_formulae[]'
node@10
node@12
node@8
```

You will need the program `jq` installed for it to drill down into the appropriate JSON, (`brew install jq`).

Since the above is gnarly to write/remember, I suggest setting up an alias or function in your favorite shell.

**Note:** This method will only work with Formulae and not Casks.

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: Good idea, just heads up, sometimes its empty.

Answer (score 46):

And in case you wanted to just look up the specific version used by a formula after finding it using `search`, you can get the `info` with:

```
brew info <formula|cask>
```

e.g. `brew info postgresql@10`, or `brew info vlc`.
(Brew no longer needs to explicitly specify `--cask` for this command.)

And if you can't find a popular old version of a cask, you may be able to get it via `homebrew-cask-versions`, which is installable with `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`.

Comment: hello! And how do I use `homebrew-cask-versions` ? I've installed it with `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` and now how do I proceed?

Comment: @mariano-daniel It should automatically add additional cask options to your `brew search` results. For example, using the `iterm` example in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions, the original 3 results (`iterm2` `therm` `zterm`) now adds: `iterm2-beta` `iterm2-legacy` `iterm2-nightly`. And if you run a `brew info` on any of them, you can see if it came from `homebrew-cask` or `homebrew-cask-versions`.

Answer (score 8):

To get the exact results without extraneous noise, you can use regex with `brew search`. It excludes `qt-postgresql` and `postgrest`, which would have been returned by `brew search postgresql`. This is especially helpful if you're searching for a short package name like `r` or `git` that would otherwise return a lot of noise.

```sh
$ brew search '/^postgresql$|^postgresql@/'

==> Formulae
postgresql          postgresql@11       postgresql@13       postgresql@9.5
postgresql@10       postgresql@12       postgresql@9.4      postgresql@9.6
```

Note, `brew search` does seem to support Extended Regex, so I couldn't use the more efficient regex below. Of course, you could use a grep pipe to accomplish the same:

```sh
$ brew search postgresql | grep -E '^postgresql(@.*)?$'

postgresql
postgresql@10
postgresql@11
postgresql@12
postgresql@13
postgresql@9.4
postgresql@9.5
postgresql@9.6
```